# how to fix Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

how to fix

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> No matching client found for package name 'com.talada.myapplication'
```

I change 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0' to 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0' and distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.12-all.zip to distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip

not working.

build.gradle(app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.talada.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

build.gradle (project)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-rc3'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.12-all.zip
```

Comment: does it work with another android studio project?

Answer (score 0):

compile with

```
dependencies {
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'
}
```

and remove

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```